# hibernate mapping where you have a Map of Lists

Tags: hibernate

Is there a way to create a hibernate mapping where you have a Map of Bags or Sets or some type of collection?

For instance, maybe I have an inventory of parts and I want to pull them into a Map like so:

```
   Map<PartType, List<Part>> inventory;
```

So PartType which might be a class or just a String is the map key.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, you need to create an intermediate class that contains the List. Your map will become :

```
Map<PartType, Parts> inventory;
```

And you need to create a new class with its own mapping :

```
public class Parts {

   private List<Part> parts;

}
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of the mapping xml?

Comment: I edited my answer. Once you've introduced the intermediate class, you are back to common collection mappings ...

Comment: So the answer is no then?  It doesn't have to be two collections it could just be a Map<Integer, List<Part>> where the key is the part type id or something like that.  Is that possible?

Comment: Map is a collection and no it's not possible.

Comment: Thank you, that is too bad.  I was hoping this might be an organized way to store a very large list so it would be faster accessing the data.  I had guessed that if that could be done hibernate would run lazy load queries on the keys, but I think I am ahead of my time.  I guess the only way to access data in a large list quickly is to just run queries.

Answer (score 0):

IMO  it should be an `Id` of `PartType` pojo

```
<map name="mymap" cascade="all">
         <key column="parttype_id"/>
            .
            .
            .

      </map>
```

Comment: But back to my real question, can the map value be a set|bag?